# Docker-compose - Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, docker-compose, pom.xml

I have three pom.xml files, where one is the parent and the two others are the children. The parent is located in a folder named calculatorws and the two children are located separately in two folders(inside the folder calculatorws): calculatorws-calculator and calculatorws-rest and each one of them contains a pom.xml file.

The parent pom.xml file is:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>calculatorws</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>calculatorws-calculator</module>
    <module>calculatorws-rest</module>
</modules>
```

The pom.xml file of calculatorws-rest is:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>calculatorws</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>calculatorws-rest</artifactId>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

The pom.xml file of calculatorws-calculator is:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>calculatorws</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>calculatorws-calculator</artifactId>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

I have three Dockerfiles respectively for the parent and the children.

The Dockerfile of the parent is:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8-alpine

COPY pom.xml /application/
WORKDIR /application/
COPY . /application/
RUN mvn clean package
```

The Dockerfile for calculatorws-rest is:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8-alpine as builder

COPY pom.xml /calculatorws-rest/
WORKDIR /calculatorws-rest/
COPY . /calculatorws-rest/

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
COPY --from=builder /calculatorws-rest/target/calculatorws-rest-0.0.1.jar /rest.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/rest.jar"]
```

The Dockerfile for calculatorws-calculator is:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8-alpine as builder

COPY pom.xml /calculatorws-calculator/
WORKDIR /calculatorws-calculator/
COPY . /calculatorws-calculator/

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
COPY --from=builder /calculatorws-calculator/target/calculatorws-calculator-0.0.1.jar /calculator.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/calculator.jar"]
```

I run the project using the docker-compose file as shown below:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
 rabbitmq:
  image: rabbitmq:3.7.3-alpine
  container_name: rabbit
  ports:
   - 5672:5672
 application:
  build: .
 calculatorws-rest:
  build: ./calculatorws-rest
 calculatorws-calculator:
  build: ./calculatorws-calculator
```

I fixed the error with the non resolvable parent POM by deleting the RUN mvn clean package from the Dockerfile of calculatorws-rest, but now I get this error:

```
No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

I think I have a problem with my structure and I am not getting it.

Comment: A parent should always define `<relativePath/>` to make sure the artifact is correctly search in a remote repository and not one directory level above...apart from that it needed to build inside the container? And the spring-boot version you are using is out of date...

Comment: I could not find calculatorws in mvnrepository? Where do you try to download from?

Comment: I believe that your project `calculatorws-rest` is part of multimodule project (if I am wrong correct me),  under another maven project `calculatorws`. And the pom.xml cannot locate the parent pom. This is an assumptions so I hope it will help

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for your answer! I have tried to add <realtivePath/> and it didn't help me. Do I need to change the version to 2.2.1 for ex? Yes, I use a container.

Comment: @MustafaGüler Actually the service calculatorws-rest is a folder inside another folder calculatorws.

Comment: Have I done something wrong with the pom.xml files?

Comment: @Aristotle The calculatorws-rest is located inside a folder named calculatorws, which contains the parent pom.xml.

Comment: @WillWost could you please share your project structure. So we could have a better understanding whats going on?

Comment: @Aristotle I reformulated my question. Can you please check it?

Comment: You miss a plugin to deal with the phases and the lifecycles, so you can install dependencies, build the project and execute it. Check Springboot maven plugin

Comment: @Aristotle What do I need to add in this case? I can't find a solution.

Comment: @Aristotle Do I need to have three dockerfiles, one for the parent and two for the children respectively?

Comment: Check this [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using). No, you need a separate dockerfile for each deployment

Comment: @Aristotle I checked the document, but I have correctly configured the dependencies between the parent and the children. I think I have a problem with my Dockerfiles, but my professor has asked me to have a Dockerfile for each service and that's why I chose this structure. I don't know how to run these dockerfiles within the docker-compose.